# How to send AppEngine requests logs to a remote logging server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, java.util.logging, splunk

We have a Java application that runs on Google App Engine and currently I am investigating a way to send the request logs to a logging server (in our case splunkstorm.com).

We are interested in the logs that GAE produces automaticaly for each request, for example:

```
0.1.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2012:05:22:29 -0700] "GET /_ah/sessioncleanup?clear HTTP/1.1" 200 29 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "map2app-platform.appspot.com" ms=307 cpu_ms=5081 api_cpu_ms=3412 cpm_usd=0.141154
```

I read that Splunk supports syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng, snare, netcat and a REST API.

My idea is to make the java.util.logging send the logs like *syslog* but didn't find any info about this. Another one is to use SLF4J and use a 3rd-party jar to send the logs but I am not sure if the request logs that GAE produces automatically will be sent.

What options do we have? Anybody had experience with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to have a cron job that fetches the logs using the [Log Service API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logservice/).

Additionally, you can download the logs using appcfg.sh, see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Logs) for details.

Comment: This how I do things manually now and if I don't find a better alternative I will just write a bash or python script.

What I am interested in my research is to find a more reliable method.